# Android logcat which app spams logcat

Tags: battery-life, 6.0-marshmallow, logging

On my Oneplus Two android phone I recently updated to android 6.0. Since then my battery life has decreased drastically. Plugged into my computer I saw that a app is spamming the logcat even when the screen is tured off and the device should sleep.

```
04-23 22:49:48.278 666-666/? W/ipacm: type=1400 audit(0.0:19622): avc: denied { sendto } for path="/dev/socket/ipacm_log_file" scontext=u:r:ipacm:s0 tcontext=u:r:ipacm-diag:s0 tclass=unix_dgram_socket permissive=0
```

This message is spamed four times every ~5 seconds. Now my question is: **How can I figure out which app is responsible for that message?**

**UPDATE:**

I have done a factory reset and the waring still appears. So I guess it's a system app / service.
Note: The waring only appears while being connected to a wifi network. It could also be the case that the warning only appears while charging.

Comment: I don't think it's from a specific app, but `W/ipacm` seems indicates a **W**arning log from *ipacm* process. However, I don't know what IPACM is. (IP ACM?)

Comment: @AndrewT. sounds like a good guess: [Multipath TCP - ACM Queue](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2591369) (really just a wild guess, didn't research it in-depth – but *the page title* sounds convincing somehow ;)